# DBeaver - how to change the program name used

Tags: database, dbeaver

When trying to connect to oracle some information are sent:

```
   Database: XXXXXX
   DB-User: XXXXXX
   OS-User: XXXXXX
   Machine: XXXXXX
   Program: DBeaver 23?2?1 ? Main
   Id: 28
```

I need to change  `Program: DBeaver 23?2?1 ? Main` to `Program: DBeaver`

Answer (score 1):

Go to your DB connection, then

Edit connection --> Connection settings --> Client identification

Then mark "Override client application name"
And just type "DBeaver" in the text field.

[image: Config]